# Code coverage for a regular execution of an Android app

Tags: android, code-coverage, instrumentation

I am trying to get code coverage in both manual and automatic UI interaction tests.
Is there a way of getting code coverage when I execute the app?

This would help me to spot the parts of the code that are used more often during standard common use case scenarios. It would explain which code in the app demands more attention.